# 500 Internal Server Error при подключении urlManager в YII приложении

Tags: nginx, php, yii

Здравствуйте! После подключения urlManager, не обрабатывается не один запрос, вылезает ошибка 500. Хотя на локалке все работает отлично. Другие сайты на этом же сервере и в этом же домене работают. 
Сервер Server nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu).

В лог-файле ошибок пишет:

```
 2014/04/30 10:00:35 [error] 1164#0: *1094451 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 77.40.56.84, server: xxxx.xxxx.ru, request: "GET /favicon.icand here is my htaccess:o HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxx.xxxx.ru"
```

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: какой .htaccess в nginx, вы чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по сообщению ошибки, в конфиге nginx в качестве index указаны index.htm и index.html. При запросе nginx пытается найти хотя бы один из них, не находит, и снова отправляется в дефолтный location, который опять будет искать индексный файл. Вам нужно поковыряться в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/{конфиг, отвечающий за сайт}` и привести его к виду, похожему на [пример](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/quickstart.apache-nginx-config): а) добавить index.php в директиву index, б) убедиться, что обработчик php работает верно (скорее всего, все и так в порядке).

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, поправил конфиг nginx

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, есть пример конфига для yii на nginx - проверь, что у тебя похоже на этот пример.

Во-вторых, надо смотреть, что за правила указаны в конфиге приложения yii

```
<?php 
// file protectes/config/main.php
//
// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    // компоненты
    'components' => array(
        // настройка роутинга
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'class' => 'UrlManager',
            // вот тут что ???
        ),
    ),
);
```